# Loading Comma Delimited Text file into a Dictionary

Tags: vb.net, string, dictionary

I want to add the contents of a comma delimited text file(PracInfo.txt) into a Dictionary on Form_Load. The contents of the file are as follows:

```
wlvc,coadmin
mrmd,thadmin
ccoa,oaadmin
bfhl,bfadmin
trty,tradmin
nppp,npadmin
```

For example, I want the wlvc to be the key and the coadmin to be the corresponding value. The code I have so far goes as follows:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim sr As New StreamReader("C:\Programming files\PracInfo.txt")
        Dim openWith As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        Do While sr.Peek <> -1
          strHold = sr.ReadLine()

          ' here I would like to use the String.Split method on strHold and then put that into the Dictionary using Dictionary.Add(Key,Value) but not sure how to do this????

        Loop    
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This has not been tested, just psuedocode

```
Do While sr.Peek <> -1
    Dim lineArray As String() = sr.ReadLine().Split(",")
    If lineArray.Length = 2 Then
        openWith.Add(lineArray(0),lineArray(1))
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Do While sr.Peek <> -1
        Dim line As String() = sr.ReadLine().Split(",")
        openWith.Add(line(0), line(1))
    Loop
```

This will read a line into an array. The array will be split on the comma. You can then reference the 0th and 1st element as the key and value respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the static method `File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt")` it will return you an array of strings, on which you can iterate and foreach element, use `.Split()` to separate the comma-delimited values, then Add them to your dictionary.

Comment: It depends on how large the text file is as to whether this is a good idea or not.